# Do I have to complete the Clash of the Titans achievement in a single run?

Tags: ftl-faster-than-light

So I finally got lucky and unlocked the crystal cruiser, the Bravais. I'd like to do 2 of the achievements for it so that I can unlock its alternate layout. Getting the No Escape achievement was relatively easy (suicidal, but easy) so now I just need 1 more; Crystal Vengeance seems *very* tricky to get deliberately, so I figured I'd go for the Clash of the Titans achievement.

It says you need to destroy 15 Rock ships (including pirate Rock ships) with the crystal cruiser. Can I do that over multiple runs, or do I have to kill 15 in a single run?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to [this forum post,](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/664216-ftl-faster-than-light/66217716) you have to destroy fifteen in a single run.

Some other tips:

1. Grab Long-Range Scanners ASAP and get into as many ship encounters as you're able.
2. Ensure that you destroy the ship. Crew-slaughtering, asphyxiation, surrenders, etc all do not count towards that 15.
3. As soon as you get to the end of Sector 1, take a good look at the map. If you've got a potential straight path of red sectors, your chances of running into more rock-controlled sectors are higher.
4. You'll need about three Rock-controlled sectors in one game to get this, but you can also snag some Rock ship kills from random pirates in nebulas.
5. Try circumventing the rebel fleet if you're able. Say you've got a bottom-right exit; clear the bottom-right of ships first, then move on to the top-right and try to fight some ships there.
6. Look for events that will delay the rebel fleet in Rock sectors, such as mercenaries, but make sure you don't hire Rock mercenaries you could potentially be destroying for the achievement.

Side note: Some tips for the Crystal Vengeance augment/Sweet Vengeance achivement: Drone kills and *accepted* surrenders that result from a shard breakoff count towards it.